# Arabic Content is displayed in weird Characters

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, ios4, multilingual

I am trying to parse the below Arabic content

```
<type id="14">
<data name="title">قافية</data>
</type>

NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSData *xmlData=[[request responseString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

when print the response i am getting as below

```
responseString:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><type>
<data name="title">ÙØ§ÙÙØ©</data>
</type>
```

please see [image: This] image attached , this is how it displays the content on my ios app

Please let me know how can i fix this

Comment: Seems me issue in encoding. Try other available encodings instead of NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below encoding,

```
// The following constants are provided by NSString as possible string encodings.

enum {
   NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,
   NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
   NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
   NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,
   NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
   NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
   NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
   NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,
   NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
   NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
   NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,
   NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,
   NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,
   NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,
   NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,
   NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,
   NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,
   NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,
   NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,
   NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,
   NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,
   NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,
   NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100,
   NSProprietaryStringEncoding = 65536
};
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. in this list which one should i use to get the arabic content to be dispalyed.

Comment: That I don't know but try using every one in this list.. just copy paste all and do NSLog for all..

Comment: Try using [NSString stringWithUTF8String:YOURSTRING]

Comment: Ohh..then if this is from webservice then tell him/her to do proper encoding from there

Comment: Are you using ASIHttpRqeuest? and touchXML?

Comment: I am using ASIHttpRequest.the xml is encoded as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14851/discussion-between-user198725878-and-mehul)

Comment: :can you pls help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all after checking your response string(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Change here" ?><type>`) it looks me issue in xml encoding type. Tell to your web developer provide proper encoding for arabic content and check it's response in browser if it showing properly  after that try various encoding at your side. It will definitely fixed.